# Which protocol is used to communicate with google firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using google firestore as my DB with a spring web service. I am using com.google.firebase package to build data access layer and to query the database.

Can someone please tell me what protocol is used underneath for communication between application and database. Is it TCP or something else ?

Atul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol is well documented. You can access it via a [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest) or a [gRPC API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/).

Answer (score 0):

It is http over TCP. All Internet traffic runs on TCP or UDP but there are usually higher protocol on top of the low level transport layer.

Comment: For MongoDB, MS SQL server client application uses TCP protocol directly. I am thinking in similar lines, for Firestore does it work same, does consuming application uses TCP protocol directly not HTTP?

Comment: You are right. But i recommend using private end points and make sure you bind it to your internal network only for security reasons.  refer below link for details.. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options   If you are doing this as a learning activity i guess without private end points will do too.